# Android: Upload image to a specific album on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was looking at the examples in the facebook SDK for Android and I was unable to figure out how to upload an image to a specific album for a user. I have already done authentication so the user can upload to private albums if necessary. Here is my upload code:

```
public void uploadFacebookPhoto(String description)
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putByteArray("picture", picData);
    params.putString("description", description);

    params.putString(SOME_IDENTIFIER, MY_ALBUM); 

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Snippet :

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putByteArray("source", imageBytes);
params.putString("message", "A wall picture");
facebook.request("ALBUM_ID/photos", params, "POST");
```

Where **ALBUM_ID** - is your Album id in which you need to post image.

For further reference check [Facebook Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts)